# Google Script changing string into date, I don't want it to

Tags: string, date, google-apps-script

I've got a script that reads the content of a cell that has the format "Mmm YYYY" i.e. Jan 2015

```
=CONCATENATE(text(today(),"MMM")," ",YEAR(NOW()))
```

When I use google script to get the value of the cell, it reads it as a date and outputs it as 01/01/2015. How can I get it to get the value as a string rather than a date?

I need it to the find a sheet in my spreadsheet call "Jan 2015" (Or whatever is relevant), so having it changing the string breaks my code.

Comment: you could convert it to text in the script.... ?

Comment: If you want the content of a cell to be plain text, you should set its cell format to plain text. Otherwise, the default automatic formatting will attempt to interpret the cell's contents before providing the value to a script. (The same applies to data that you want to use as a datatable for Google Visualizations, by the way.)

Answer (score 0):

There is an open request for a native function to override this feature. https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=402

The last two user replies offer Libraries you can install to extend GAS to include it.

Or if that is too heavyweight, use the `Utilities.formatDate()` function on values already retrieved.